# WiFi problems (Atheros driver) with FreeBSD 11

Tags: wifi, freebsd

With FreeBSD 10.3 my Atheros card worked fine and showed up as `/dev/ath0`. Now with FreeBSD 11 this is no longer the case, though the module is loaded and it seems the system recognizes the card:

```
root@igloo:~ # sysctl net.wlan.devices
net.wlan.devices: ath0
```

Still, `ath0` cannot be used:

```
root@igloo:~ # ifconfig wlan0 create wlandevice ath0
ifconfig: must specify a parent device (wlandev) when creating
```

What must I do to use the card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says you need to use `wlandev` rather than `wlandevice`.

Try:

```
ifconfig wlan0 create wlandev ath0
```

More information and examples can be found [here in the ath(4) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ath&section=4&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Answer (score 0):

To configure the network , edit your `/etc/rc.conf` by adding the following line ( to configure the network on startup):

```
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA SYNCDHCP"
```

Create a wlan interface:

```
ifconfig wlan0 create wlandev ath0
```

Scan for access points:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up scan
```

Create a `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` configuration file with the following contents:

```
network={
ssid="your_ssid"
psk="your_password"
}
```

Connect:

To connect you need to restart the network service:

```
service netif restart
```

After restarting the network service, the wifi should work.

Also you can connect through `wpa_supplicant`:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my experience to this thread.
I am convering an old Asus P5G41T-MLX machine to run FreeBSD 11.1
Initally it would not find the Atheros AR8131-BL1A device.
Updating the BIOS resolved the problem