# FreeBSD - wireless cards not picked up

Tags: wifi, freebsd

I am attempting to get wireless working on FreeBSD 11.1 and not having much luck.  Dmesg indicates it sees the USB wireless adapter; however, ifconfig and sysctl net.wlan.devices indicate nothing.

dmesg output

```
Realtek 802.11ac NIC
Atheros USB2.0 WLAN
Atheros UB94
```

I tried man ath - added the entries to /boot/loader.conf, rebooted, and nothing.

Are these devices not supported or is something else going on?

From what little I know, I do not believe this to be related to this: [WiFi problems (Atheros driver) with FreeBSD 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326712/wifi-problems-atheros-driver-with-freebsd-11)

I do not even have /dev/ath0, if I did, I would be a little further along to getting wireless working.

The only thing I see is output in dmesg as listed.

Comment: So you've added `if_ath_load="YES"` and `if_ath_pci_load="YES"` to loader.conf and `sysctl net.wlan.devices` still does not show any device, right?

Comment: 1. Why would I need if_ath_pci_load="YES"  if it is a USB device?  2. The device isn't even showing up at all, so I need to sort that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one of the unsupported Atheros wireless NICs.